# Why the checkbox doesn't work in this reactive inner object?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Why is the checkbox not working here?

I think Svelte is re-evaluating `innerTeam` on change, but I don't understand why.

I'm changing `innerTeam` not `team`.

I'm using that reactive syntax to change `innterTeam` only if `team` changes! Not the other way!

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/1ef7657adbc545a0b595e2ab58069b4a?version=3.42.4

- App.svelte:

```
<script>
    import {onMount} from "svelte";
    import Inner from "./Inner.svelte"
    
    let team = {
        player: {id: "1", name: "John"},
        full: false
    }
    
    onMount(() => setTimeout(()=> {
        team = { player: {id: "2", name: "Bob"} }
    }, 4000))
</script>

team: <pre>{JSON.stringify(team, null, 2)}</pre>

<Inner {team}></Inner>
```

- Inner.svelte:

```
<script>        
    export let team = undefined;
    
    let innerTeam;
    
    $: innerTeam = {
        ...team,
        cars: []
    }
    
    function addCar() {
        innerTeam.cars = [...innerTeam.cars, {id: "1", brand: "BMW"}]
    }   
</script>

<button on:click={addCar}>
    Add car to customTeam
</button>

<br>

<input bind:checked={innerTeam.full} type="checkbox"/> Full?

<br>

customTeam: <pre>{JSON.stringify(innerTeam, null, 2)}</pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using that reactive syntax to change innterTeam only if team changes! Not the other way!

Well not really. You're making a reactive declaration about `innerTeam` so anytime that `innerTeam` or `team` changes `innerTeam` will be updated. In your case `innerTeam.full` is a value coming from `team` and you're telling Svelte whenever `innerTeam` changes reset `innerTeam` equal to `...team, cars: []` you change full to true, Svelte changes it back like you told it to.

If you want the reactivity to be based around `team` you can make a reactive statement about `team` and have it call a function that updates `innerTeam`:

```js
let innerTeam

function updateInner() {
    innerTeam = {
        ...team,
        cars: []
    }
}
    
$: team, updateInner()
```

However, doing it this way means when the team is updated any cars added will go away. Not sure if this is what you wanted or not, but it seems like what you described.

Here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3d6c679ea2a64d74b254b0edab9877af?version=3.42.4) showing the behavior, if you add cars and click the Increase ID# button the cars go away.